# If $x_{k} \rightarrow x$ and $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}||x_{m}-y_{m}||=0$, then $y_{m} \rightarrow x$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Let $\{x_{m}\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{y_{m}\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be succesions in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.If $x_{k} \rightarrow x$ and $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}||x_{m}-y_{m}||=0$, then $y_{m} \rightarrow x$.

So far I have

$$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}||x_{m}-y_{m}||=0\Leftrightarrow x_{m} \rightarrow y_{m}$$

and

$$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}||y_{m}-x||=0\Leftrightarrow y_{m} \rightarrow x$$

which means

$$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}||y_{m}-x||=\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}||x_{m}-x||$$

which tempts me to conclude $y_{m}=x_{m}$ and therefore $y_{m} \rightarrow x$, but I think it's very possible I am mistaken.

Comment: what does $x_m\to y_m$ mean?

Comment: Is a “succession” a sequence?

Comment: Or a slightly nuanced terminology (ordinarily the words mean the same but perhaps in maths it’s different)? I ask because I’ve never seen it before

Comment: Hint: $\|y_m-x\|=\|y_m-x_m+x_m-x\|\leq $...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is certainly no reason $x_m=y_m$. Consider $x_m=1/m$ and $y_m=0$ for all $m$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and take $N_1$ such that $n>N_1$ implies $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon/2$.

Now take $N_2$ such that $n>N_2$ implies $|y_n-x_n|<\varepsilon/2$.

Finally, take $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and finish up with the triangle inequality.